# Large Swagger Json file into multi json files

Tags: json, flask, swagger, flask-restful, api-documentation

Hey Everyone So I am using lib `flask-swagger-ui==4.11.1` in my flask application to host api documentation.
The `swagger.json` now has become around 10000 of lines. So to avoid problems like merge conflicts and management I wrote a python script that will merge different json files(one will defines path, other will define schemas, other will define security components) into 1 json file(swagger.json).

But what I want to know if there are any other industry standards that everyone should follow facing this kind of problem as I am not sure If my approach is good enough.